# Is there any android multimedia frameworks for creating multimedia pipelines (like Directshow, Gstreamer)?

Tags: android, frameworks, multimedia

I want to learn to develop applications on Android platform. I have some expierence with Linux and .Net development.

Is there any specific frameworks in android to create multimedia pipelines? Pipelines are powerfull tools in multimedia processing and even for the simple playback manipulation and I feel them way more comfortable traditional direct codec decoding aproach. In Windows example of such type of framework is Directshow, in Linux - GStreamer. Is there something like that runing in Android environment?

Comment: [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.com/) `With the SDK, get the most out of GStreamer to create world-class multimedia applications for all form factors running Linux, Mac OS X, Windows and Android.`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that there is android sdk version of Gstreamer. I will try to use it.